# Getting no response from Fetch API ( in React native with Laravel API )

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-native, laravel-5.3, fetch-api

I am using React native 0.44 , Fetch API and Laravel 5.3 API.

when I try to fetch the URL using the Fetch API, it gives no output or response.

As `localhost:8000` was not working in Fetch API, I tried using the wifi ipaddress.

```
    doSignUp() {

     console.log("inside post api");
     fetch('http://192.168.43.244:8000/api/user?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0NywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDBcL2FwaVwvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk2MjA0ODgwLCJleHAiOjE0OTYyMDg0ODAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5NjIwNDg4MCwianRpIjoiRGdtSDNSWXl4MEtUZWs2YSJ9.yc0FvK5uJz8rzDWAZLwweDMrz6ljTWkTzvxgtCjEqAc', {
           method: 'GET',
            headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJSON) => console.log("inside responsejson"))
        .catch(e=>console.error(e))
        .done();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and i resolved it using npm es6-promise and isomorphic-fetch package.Give it a try

```
 import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

and you can use it like

```
fetch('/holidays/occasion', {
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
           state: evt.target.value
         })
        });
      },
```

Comment: using above packages ->getting error : `fetch(...).then(...).then(...).catch(...).done is not a function`

Comment: also ,how i use fetch variable u declared

Comment: btw it still not identifying then function usin this  packages

Comment: you have to install isomorphic-fetch and es6-promise in your package like in my project i have installed them using npm install es6-promise and then import that dependency

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the status is ok, by trying,

```
fetch('http://192.168.43.244:8000/api/user?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0NywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDBcL2FwaVwvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk2MjA0ODgwLCJleHAiOjE0OTYyMDg0ODAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5NjIwNDg4MCwianRpIjoiRGdtSDNSWXl4MEtUZWs2YSJ9.yc0FvK5uJz8rzDWAZLwweDMrz6ljTWkTzvxgtCjEqAc', {
method: 'GET',
            headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }}).(res => {
 if (res.status === 'OK') {
   console.log('I should be getting the data')
   return res.json() 
 }
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: sry nothing happens :(

Comment: are you sure your `doSignUp()` function is being fired?

Comment: yes m sure cz i can see `inside post api` in console

Answer (score 0):

run the command  adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000 and reload the app again.

Comment: tried your method `Authorization`:'Bearer token` ..still nothing :(

Comment: Can you try consoling only the response (not response.json()) and check whether you were able to see anything

Comment: Can you try fetching this url 

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json 
just to check wether any issue with url

Comment: it returned the object ...maybe u r ryt...so whats the issue then?

Comment: Can you hit your url using postman and check wether you are able to see the response

Comment: yes m getting response in postman but here i have used ip address of wifi as mentioned in the issues of react native.using localhost give me error network request failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145512/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-sooraj-c).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is a low-level library that really isn't recommended if you wanna keep your sanity. In fact, fetch only rejects a promise when network errors are encountered. All other http errors will go into your then block where you check `if (response.ok)`

For my react-native project, I'm using this package [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

Besides, do note if you're on an iOS react-native project, any addresses other than your localhost will be rejected and may fail silently because all communication other than https is not allowed because of 
[App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b). I believe this is what you're facing

Answer (score 0):

why are you are using method Get,Header kind of AJAX request. you can use simple fetch explained in react official documentation.[react-native fetch api](http://192.168.43.244:8000/api/user?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0NywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDBcL2FwaVwvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk2MjA0ODgwLCJleHAiOjE0OTYyMDg0ODAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5NjIwNDg4MCwianRpIjoiRGdtSDNSWXl4MEtUZWs2YSJ9.yc0FvK5uJz8rzDWAZLwweDMrz6ljTWkTzvxgtCjEqAc)

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using production server url.

The problem was fetch api and also axios cant access localhost .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the key-value pair `credentials: 'include'` in your fetch options. RN 0.44 introduced the withCredentials XHR flag, as you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14063).